# Interior of a Dirichlet domain in a Riemannian manifold

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $X\neq\varnothing$ be a complete connected Riemannian manifold. Suppose $G$ is a group of isometries of $X$, acting properly discontinuously on $X$. We assume there is a point $x_0\in X$ such that $g(x_0)\neq x_0$ when $g\neq\mathrm{id}$ and a set $$D=\{x\in X\mid \mathrm d(x,x_0)\leq\mathrm d(x,g(x_0))\quad\forall g\in G\}.$$

Is it true that $\mathrm{int}(D)$ contains at most one point out of each orbit? A possibility would be $$\mathrm{int}(D)\overset?=\{x\in X\mid \mathrm d(x,x_0)<\mathrm d(x,g(x_0))\quad\forall g\in G\setminus\{\mathrm{id}\}\}.$$ And is $\mathrm{int}(D)\neq\varnothing$?

Comment: Please, reread your question: For every subset $D$ in any topological space $X$, $int(D)$ is contained in $D$. As for your second question, yes, $x_0$ lies in the interior of $D$ (which is quite clear from the definition).

Comment: @studiosus You are very right of course. My previous edit was not very consistent. I have changed the question. However, for your answer to my second question, I don't follow immediately.